# New dataframe column for count of rows with certain value in a column , with same customer ID column and less than date and time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

EDITED  
I want to add a new column called prev_message_left which counts the no. of messages_left per ID less than the date prior the given time. Basically I want to have a column which says how many times we had left message on call to that customer prior to the current time and date. This is how my data frame looks like

```
date       ID   call_time   message_left  
20191101    1        8:00              0
20191102    2        9:00              1
20191030    1       16:00              1
20191103    2       10:30              1
20191105    2       14:00              0
20191030    1       15:30              0
```

I want to add an additional column called prev_message_left_count

```
date       ID   call_time   message_left  prev_message_left_count
20191101    1        8:00              0                        1
20191102    2        9:00              1                        0
20191030    1       16:00              1                        0
20191103    2       10:30              1                        1
20191105    2       14:00              0                        2
20191030    1       15:30              0                        0
```

My dataframe has 15 columns and 90k rows.
I have various other columns in this dataframe and there are columns like 'No Message Left', 'Responded' for which I will have to compute additional columns called 'Previous_no_message_left' and 'prev_responded' similar to 'prev_message_left'

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `cumcount` after `sort_values`

```
df['pervious']=df.sort_values(['date','call_time']).groupby('ID').cumcount()
df
       date  ID call_time  message_left  pervious
0  20191101   1      8:00             0         2
1  20191102   2      9:00             1         0
2  20191030   1     16:00             1         1
3  20191103   2     10:30             1         1
4  20191105   2     14:00             0         2
5  20191030   1     15:30             0         0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify me on how/where did you consider message_left column?

Comment: I have various other columns in this dataframe and there are columns like 'No Message Left', 'Responded' for which I will have to compute additional columns called 'Previous_no_message_left' and 'prev_responded' similar to 'prev_message_left'